# TypeError: findall() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, regex

posted a much worse version of this question before. I've calmed down, refined my searches and I've almost figured out what I need. I'm trying to extract all the words ending in "ing" from a decently sized text file. Also, I'm supposed to be using regex but that has me incredibly confused, so at this point I'm just trying to get the results I need. here's my code:

```
import re

file = open('ing words.txt', 'r')
pattern = re.compile("\w+ing")

print re.findall(r'>(\w+ing<')
```

here's what I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-861693e3a217> in <module>()
      3 pattern = re.compile("\w+ing")
      4 
----> 5 print re.findall(r'>(\w+ing<')

TypeError: findall() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I'm still very new at this, and I don't know exactly why the second argument is needed (i know that the short answer is "because", but I'd like to know the theory if someone could take the time to explain it), but more-so how to add a second argument that won't break my code even further. I'm confident (but probably wrong) that after " print re.findall(r'>(\w+ing<') " I need some way of re-telling my terminal that it needs to search within that ing words.txt.

Am I even close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass two arguments to [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) or call it as `pattern` method:

```
print pattern.findall(file.read())
print re.findall(r'>(\w+ing<', file.read())
```

or

```
for line in file:
    print pattern.findall(file.read())
    print re.findall(r'>(\w+ing<', line)
```

Suggestion: It's better to work with file by using [With](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) statement.

```
with open('ing words.txt', 'r') as file:
    print pattern.findall(file.read())
    print re.findall(r'>(\w+ing<', file.read())
```

Comment: You skipped over the precompiled pattern; they just forgot to use it.

Comment: Thank you, after that suggestion, it worked!

I actually got it working a few minutes prior to your solution, but it wasn't the prettiest of things. However, I now know the correct method.

Answer (score 4):

[`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) requires at least 2 arguments to be provided - a pattern itself and the string to search in. You though meant to use `pattern.findall()` instead:

```
print pattern.findall(r'>(\w+ing<')
```

Comment: Okay, we're cooking with gas. Syntax error is gone, but my printout is simply "[]". for lack of a better term, it seems i'm missing some kind of "callback" to the .txt . does that go somewhere underneath " pattern = re.compile..... "?